# Bug in close-vote tallies

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

[This ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117339/how-do-i-list-within-a-sentence) has a bug in its close-vote totals.  I’m posting it here because I suspect the bug is related to the new close-vote system, and therefore would be network-wide.

It says it has four close votes on it:

[image: bug shot 1]

But when you open the dialogue, it shows only two:

[image: bug shot 2]

And that notion persists in the sub-dialogue:

[image]

Comment: Presumably 2 of the votes are for some other close reason that doesn't map 1-1 with new reasons, such as too localized.